# Ask the compiler to dump the implicitly instantiated templates

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, explicit-instantiation

I am working on a library which use intensively Eigen for its dense algebra operations. We have a database of 'end-to-end' tests, each one of them being a translation unit in which tens (hundreds, thousands?) of Eigen's functions are instanciated. But a lot of these functions are used in many test cases, and so are instantiated many times.

So I would like to get the list of Eigen's functions that are used in my test base, and generate a file that will instantiated them once for all.

To this end, I tried to write a python script which call and process the output of some `nm` commands to get the symbol instantiated in my test base. But the problem is that it appears that for non-template member functions, the symbol reported by `nm` does not contains the returned type of the function, which I need to explicitly instantiate it. And if I try to explicitly instantiate the whole class (all of its member functions), it does not work because all of the member functions of an Eigen's class are not meant to be instantiated. As an example, the following snippet does not compile:

```cpp
#include "Eigen/Dense"
template class Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>;
```

It fails with the error message:

```
error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>::IsVectorAtCompileTime && Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>::SizeAtCompileTime == 4' "THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS_OF_A_SPECIFIC_SIZE"
      EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_SPECIFIC_SIZE(Matrix, 4)
```

Furthermore, even if it worked, instantiating the whole classes would be a bit overkill because I only need a small subset of their member functions...

So I would like to find another way than processing some `nm` output to get the Eigen's templates that are instantiated in my test base. And I couldn't find how to ask the compiler to tell me about the templates that it implicitly instantiated...

Do you have any idea?

---

[EDIT: extra question]
Why does the standard requires the return type to be specified when explicitly instantiating a non-template member function of a template class?

Also, I don't understand why this is 'fair' that the following does not work:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct A {
    double f() {return 2.0;}
};
template auto A<int>::f();
```

whereas this compiles:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct A {
    auto f() {return 2.0;}
};
template auto A<int>::f();
```

---

Comment: If you want information from your compiler it would help if you told us which compiler that actually is.

Comment: https://cppinsights.io/ might help?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would use whatever c++ compiler that would do the trick on linux!